# LibUsbDotNet sends only the first byte on write

Tags: c#, usb, libusbdotnet

I am using LibUsbDotNet for reading and writing to usb in C#, but when write to the USB it only sends the first byte, so special configuration is required on UsbEndpointWriter or UsbDevice?  Even if I test the SerialPort class for sending data, I have the same problem.

The PC detects the USB as a virtual com port.

My USB device descriptor:

```
STMicroelectronics.- STMicroelectronics Virtual COM Port
OSVersion: Microsoft Windows NT 6.2 .9200 .0 LibUsbDotNet
Version: 2.2 .8 .104
DriverMode: LibUsb
Length: 18
DescriptorType: Device
BcdUsb: 0x0200
Class: Comm
SubClass: 0x02
Protocol: 0x00
MaxPacketSize0: 64
VendorID: 0x0483
ProductID: 0x5740
BcdDevice: 0x0200
ManufacturerStringIndex: 1
ProductStringIndex: 2
SerialStringIndex: 3
ConfigurationCount: 1
ManufacturerString: Altin Payesh Sanat
    ,Inc.
ProductString: Altins Mono Recorder
SerialString: 00000000001 A
```

CONFIG #1 Length:9

```
  DescriptorType:Configuration TotalLength:67 InterfaceCount:2 ConfigID:1 
  StringIndex:0 Attributes:0xC0 MaxPower:50 ConfigString:
```

INTERFACE (0,0) Length:9

```
 DescriptorType:Interface InterfaceID:0 AlternateID:0 EndpointCount:1 
 Class:Comm SubClass:0x02 Protocol:0x01 StringIndex:0 InterfaceString:
```

ENDPOINT 0x82 Length:7

```
 DescriptorType:Endpoint EndpointID:0x82 Attributes:0x03 MaxPacketSize:8 
 Interval:16 Refresh:0 SynchAddress:0x00
```

INTERFACE (1,0) Length:9

```
 DescriptorType:Interface InterfaceID:1 AlternateID:0 EndpointCount:2 
 Class:Data SubClass:0x00 Protocol:0x00 StringIndex:0 InterfaceString:
```

ENDPOINT 0x01 Length:7

```
 DescriptorType:Endpoint EndpointID:0x01 Attributes:0x02 MaxPacketSize:64 
 Interval:0 Refresh:0 SynchAddress:0x00
```

ENDPOINT 0x81 Length:7

```
 DescriptorType:Endpoint EndpointID:0x81 Attributes:0x02 MaxPacketSize:64 
 Interval:0 Refresh:0 SynchAddress:0x00
```

Comment: Improve readability, spelling and grammar

Comment: @Anthony-Horne thank you for improve readability

Comment: Can somebody help?
some programs like https://sites.google.com/site/terminalbpp/ work well